# Issue with maintaining a MySQL WooCommerce Customer Table

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce, pdo

Well, I'm afraid that I will not be able to post a minimum reproducible example, and for that I apologize. But, here goes nothing.

Ours is a weekly prepared meals service. I track order volume in many ways. Here is the structure of the relevant table:

[image: Column headings of customer data table]

So then I utilize the highlighted fields in many ways, such as indicating to delivery drivers if a customer is returning from the prior order being more than a month ago (last_order_w - prev_order_w > 4), for instance.

Lately I have been noticing that the data is not consistently updating properly. In the past 3 weeks, I would say it is an occurrence of 5%. If it were more consistent, I would be more confident in my ability to track down the issue, but I am not even sure how to provoke it, as I only really notice it after the fact.

The code that should cause the update is below:

```
<?php   
    //retrieve and iterate over IDs of orders placed since last synchronization.
    $newOrders=array_map('reset',$dbh->query("select id from wp_posts where id > (select max(synced) from fitaf_weeks) and post_type='shop_order' and post_status='wc-processing'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)); 
    foreach($newOrders as $no){
    
        //retrieve the metadata for the current order
        $newMetas=array_map('reset',$dbh->query("select meta_key,meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id=$no")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE));
        
        //check if the current order is associated with an existing customer
        $exist=$dbh->query("select * from fitaf_customers where id=".$newMetas['_customer_user'])->fetch();
        
        //if not, gather the information we want to store from this post
        $noExist=[$newMetas['_customer_user'],$newMetas['_shipping_first_name'],$newMetas['_shipping_last_name'],$newMetas['_shipping_address_1'],(strlen($newMetas['_shipping_address_2'])==0?NULL:$newMetas['_shipping_address_2']),$newMetas['_shipping_city'],$newMetas['_shipping_state'],$newMetas['_shipping_postcode'],$phone,$newMetas['_billing_email'],1,1,$no,$newMetas['_paid_date'],$week[3],$newMetas['_order_total']];
        if($exist){
        
            //if we found a record in the customer table, retrieve the data we want to modify
            $oldO=$dbh->query("select last_order_id,last_order,last_order_w,lo,num_orders from fitaf_customers where id=".$newMetas['_customer_user'])->fetch(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
            
            //make changes to the retrieved data, and make sure we are storing the most recently used delivery address and prepare the data points for the update command
            $exists=[$phone,$newMetas['_shipping_first_name'],$newMetas['_shipping_last_name'],$newMetas['_shipping_postcode'],$newMetas['_shipping_address_1'],(strlen($newMetas['_shipping_address_2'])==0?NULL:$newMetas['_shipping_address_2']),$newMetas['_shipping_city'],$newMetas['_shipping_state'],$newMetas['_paid_date'],$no,$week[3],$oldO['last_order'],$oldO['last_order_id'],$oldO['last_order_w'],($oldO['num_orders']+1),($oldO['lo']+$newMetas['_order_total']),$newMetas['_customer_user']];
        }
        
        
        if(!$exist){
        
            //if the customer did not exist, perform an insert
            $dbh->prepare("insert into fitaf_customers(id,fname,lname,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip,phone,email,num_orders,num_weeks,last_order_id,last_order,last_order_w,lo) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")->execute($noExist);
        }
        else{
        
            //if the customer did exist, update their data
            $dbh->prepare("update fitaf_customers set phone=?,fname=?,lname=?,zip=?,addr1=?,addr2=?,city=?,`state`=?,last_order=?,last_order_id=?,last_order_w=?,prev_order=?,prev_order_id=?,prev_order_w=?,num_orders=?,lo=? where id=?")->execute($exists);
        }
    }
    
    //finally retrieve the most recent post ID and update the field we check against when the syncornization script runs
    $lastPlaced=$dbh->query('select max(id) from wp_posts where post_type="shop_order"')->fetch()[0];
    $updateSync=$dbh-> query("update fitaf_weeks set synced=$lastPlaced order by id desc limit 1");
?>
```

Unfortunately I don't have any relevant error logs to show, however, as I documented the code for this post, I realized a *potential* shortcoming. I should be utilizing the data retrieved from the initial query of new posts, rather than a selecting the highest post id after performing this logic. However, I have timers running on my scripts, and this section hasn't taken over 3 seconds to run in a long time. So it seems unlikely, that the script, which runs on a cron every 5 minutes, is experiencing this unintended overlap?

While I have made the change to pop the highest ID off of $newOrders, and hope it solves the issue, I am still curious to see if anyone has any insights on what could cause this logic to fail at such a low occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely your problem comes from race conditions between multiple operations accessing your db.

First of all, your last few lines of code do `SELECT MAX(ID)` and then uses that value to update something. You Can't Do That™. If somebody else adds a row to that `wp_posts` table anytime after the entry you think is relevant, you'll use the wrong ID.  I don't understand your app well enough to recommend a fix. But I do know this is a serious and notorious problem.

You have another possible race condition as well. Your logic is this:

1. SELECT something.
2. make a decision based on what you SELECTED.
3. INSERT or UPDATE based on that decision.

If some other operation, done by some other user of the db, intervenes between step 1 and step 3, your decision might be wrong.

You fix this with a db transaction. The [`->beginTransaction()` operation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), well, begins the  transaction. The [`->commit()` operation concludes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php)  it.  And, the SELECT operation you use for step one [should say `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

Comment: Thanks O., for providing a knowledgeable reply. My first reaction was "I am the only user of the database so why do I have need for transactions?" and to a certain extent, I still feel that way. My wp_posts is synchronized from the production database and lives on my server, a mirror.

Anyway, the synchronization script fires on a cron every 5 minutes. That is the only time the tables are modified, so thinking further about it I don't know that this can be the issue. The synchronization occurs, the analysis occurs and no one is touching the data in between.

Comment: I guess I will take that back. The sync script can also fire from a user visiting a URL. So I suppose you are right, it is probably occurring when the cron is firing and I  pull the GUI version at the same time. As much as I do think your advice is warranted and transactions are something I should add to my toolbox, I am not sure I have time to learn and implement them just now. So my new approach is instead of re-querying to get the `MAX(ID)`, I pop off the highest ID from the `$newOrders` array. With the additional info on my setup, do you think this is an adequate band-aid for now?

Comment: Yes.  Getting the ID from someplace that got it directly from the [`->lastInsertId()` value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) after the INSERT you're looking for is exactly the right thing to do. *Nevertheless,* if you're handling other peoples' money you eventually need to do this transaction stuff correctly.